# MongoDb Gridstore Error

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I have been getting this error for months not being able to save to the out of the box mongodb Gridstore. This is the only error message I constantly get. Any thoughts?

```
Uncaught internal server error. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileData' of undefined] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileData' of undefined
    at getHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers/FilesRouter.js:69:22)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:349:14)
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
```